# Installing Mali Drivers? (ArchLinuxARM)

Tags: arm, gpu, opengl, chrome-book, arch-arm

I've recently gotten hold of an ARM-based [Chromebook C100P](https://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv7/rockchip/asus-chromebook-flip-c100p). After successfully installing ArchLinuxARM, I've struggled to enable the Mali-T764 GPU. The recommended drivers for the device, ([xf86-video-armsoc-rockchip](https://github.com/mmind/xf86-video-armsoc) and [veyron-libgl](https://github.com/archlinuxarm/PKGBUILDs/tree/master/alarm/veyron-libgl)) don't register properly within Xorg, leading to encounters with the following errors:

`Can't set the DRM interface version`

`Can't open a connection with the DRM - Permission denied`

This *isn't* an issue regarding privileges because `startx` was launched as `root`.

Other combinations such as using lightdm as the launcher, or just using the `xf86-video-fbdev` driver instead of those recommended allow me to achieve a graphics context, but none of these are hardware accelerated; they merely achieve direct rendering via llvmpipe. This is confirmed via `mesa-demos`'s `glxinfo`.

I've found [ARM's driver page](http://malideveloper.arm.com/resources/drivers/arm-mali-midgard-gpu-user-space-drivers/) and I'm planning to install the specific driver for my GPU, butI'm at a loss of where to begin. The downloadable library contains a bunch of `.so` files, but I have no idea how to integrate these within Arch; I'd appreciate if anyone is able to offer a suitable procedure.

Comment: `.so` files are **S**hared **O**bject files, essentially shared libraries with functions and routines which applications can link to and use, without having to implement them directly. From the description above the download links on the page, they seem to only provide part of the driver and are designed to work with other kernel ones - however, I cannot comment on that.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. So you think I may have to stitch a couple of libraries together? I'll try to see if there's any example implementations. :-)

Comment: This might help - https://archlinuxarm.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=5979

Comment: Even if you enable this, glxinfo won't tell you what you need. Mali T driver for veyron is an OpenGLES driver. You want to be using eglinfo / eglgears rather than the glx* tools you're used to.