# X11 crashing on login (Arch ARM)

Tags: x11, gpu, arch-arm

I am using Arch Linux on a Chromebook C201 (ARM). Since I recently upgraded the system, the desktop environment seems to be crashing shortly after I login (before the upgrade it was working fine). I have both LXDE and MATE installed and I am seeing similar crashes on both. The two DEs are using different Window Managers (Openbox and marco), so I suspect there may be an issue with X server.

When the system crashes, the screen freezes and the desktop completely locks up. There is no response to mouse or keyboard input and I am unable to use `CTL-ALT-F2` etc. to switch to a console tty. After a few minutes it dumps me back in the lightdm login screen.

I have found the following errors (which seem to be relevant) in `~/.cache/lxsession/LXDE/run.log`:

```
** (lxpanel:524): WARNING **: 21:18:33.907: The directory '~/Templates' doesn't exist, ignoring it

** (pcmanfm:525): WARNING **: 21:18:33.907: The directory '~/Templates' doesn't exist, ignoring it
Openbox-Message: Unable to find a valid menu file "/usr/share/lxde/openbox/menu.xml"

(lxpanel:524): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 21:18:34.467: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(lxpanel:524): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 21:18:34.467: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(lxpanel:524): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 21:18:34.476: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

** (lxpanel:524): WARNING **: 21:18:34.544: Battery entry BAT0 not found, using sbs-20-000b

(lxpanel:524): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 21:18:34.547: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(lxpanel:524): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 21:18:34.547: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

** (lxpanel:524): WARNING **: 21:18:34.736: launchbar: desktop entry does not exist

(nm-applet:541): libnotify-WARNING **: 21:18:38.692: Failed to connect to proxy

(nm-applet:541): nm-applet-WARNING **: 21:18:38.698: Failed to show notification: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Notifications was not provided by any .service files
lxterminal

(lxpanel:524): Wnck-WARNING **: 21:18:40.000: Unhandled action type _OB_WM_ACTION_UNDECORATE

(lxpanel:524): Wnck-WARNING **: 21:19:12.727: Unhandled action type _OB_WM_ACTION_UNDECORATE

(lxpanel:524): Wnck-WARNING **: 21:19:12.861: Unhandled action type _OB_WM_ACTION_UNDECORATE
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox 

(lxpanel:524): Wnck-WARNING **: 21:19:36.058: Unhandled action type _OB_WM_ACTION_UNDECORATE
(END)
```

The equivalent errors for MATE (from `~/.xsession-errors`) are:

```
mate-session[1216]: WARNING: Unable to find provider '' of required component 'dock'
Window manager warning: Log level 128: unsetenv() is not thread-safe and should not be used after threads are created

(caja:1299): Gtk-WARNING **: 21:22:12.818: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.gnome.SessionManager.AlreadyRegistered: Unable to register client

(mate-power-manager:1337): Gdk-CRITICAL **: 21:22:14.720: gdk_window_thaw_toplevel_updates: assertion 'window->update_and_descendants_freeze_count > 0' failed
Gdk-Message: 21:25:19.408: mate-power-manager: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.

Gdk-Message: 21:25:19.408: evolution-alarm-notify: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.

Gdk-Message: 21:25:19.409: mate-session: Fatal IO error 104 (Connection reset by peer) on X server :0.

Gdk-Message: 21:25:19.409: marco: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.

Gdk-Message: 21:25:19.415: caja: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.

Gdk-Message: 21:25:19.413: polkit-mate-authentication-agent-1: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.

Gdk-Message: 21:25:19.409: mate-maximus: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.

Gdk-Message: 21:25:19.408: mate-volume-control-status-icon: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.

Gdk-Message: 21:25:19.408: nm-applet: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.

Gdk-Message: 21:25:19.409: mate-screensaver: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.

Gdk-Message: 21:25:19.415: mate-settings-daemon: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.

Gdk-Message: 21:25:19.423: mate-panel: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
```

Contents of Xorg.0.log:

```
[    10.124] 
X.Org X Server 1.20.7
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    10.124] Build Operating System: Linux Arch Linux
[    10.124] Current Operating System: Linux leeLibrebook 5.5.6-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Feb 26 00:56:53 UTC 2020 armv7l
[    10.124] Kernel command line: cros_secure console=tty0 init=/sbin/init root=PARTUUID=1b19e700-f9cb-f247-bc7f-207dece4cdb7/PARTNROFF=1 rootwait rw noinitrd 
[    10.124] Build Date: 16 January 2020  05:49:11PM
[    10.124]  
[    10.124] Current version of pixman: 0.38.4
[    10.124]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    10.124] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    10.124] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Tue Mar 17 21:57:41 2020
[    10.125] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    10.125] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    10.125] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[    10.125] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[    10.125] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[    10.125] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[    10.125] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    10.125] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    10.125] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    10.125] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[    10.125] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[    10.126] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/misc" does not exist.
[    10.126]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    10.126] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/OTF" does not exist.
[    10.126]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    10.126] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/Type1" does not exist.
[    10.126]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    10.126] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/100dpi" does not exist.
[    10.126]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    10.126] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/75dpi" does not exist.
[    10.126]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    10.126] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/TTF
[    10.126] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    10.126] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    10.126] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    10.126]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    10.126]    X.Org Video Driver: 24.1
[    10.126]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[    10.126]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[    10.127] (++) using VT number 7

[    10.127] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[    10.129] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[    10.143] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
[    10.144] (II) no primary bus or device found
[    10.144]    falling back to /sys/devices/platform/display-subsystem/drm/card0
[    10.144] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    10.144] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[    10.148] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    10.148]    compiled for 1.20.7, module version = 1.0.0
[    10.148]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[    10.148] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 0
[    10.148] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 1
[    10.148] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    10.148] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    10.148] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    10.149] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    10.149]    compiled for 1.20.7, module version = 1.20.7
[    10.149]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    10.149]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.1
[    10.149] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    10.150] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module fbdev
[    10.150] (EE) Failed to load module "fbdev" (module does not exist, 0)
[    10.150] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[    10.160] (II) modeset(0): using drv /dev/dri/card0
[    10.160] (II) modeset(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[    10.160] (==) modeset(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[    10.160] (==) modeset(0): RGB weight 888
[    10.160] (==) modeset(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    10.160] (II) Loading sub module "glamoregl"
[    10.160] (II) LoadModule: "glamoregl"
[    10.161] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so
[    10.173] (II) Module glamoregl: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    10.173]    compiled for 1.20.7, module version = 1.0.1
[    10.173]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    10.193] (EE) 
[    10.193] (EE) Backtrace:
[    10.193] (EE) 
[    10.193] (EE) Segmentation fault at address 0xdda8
[    10.193] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[    10.193] (EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
[    10.193] (EE) 
[    10.193] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[    10.193] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[    10.193] (EE) 
[    10.200] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this? I have run `memtester` (as suggested in the comments) and it didn't identify any issues with the RAM. The system seems perfectly stable in a console terminal.

It's possible the issue is just a bad package from Arch ARM, which has broken the system during the last update. Does anyone have any thoughts on what package is likely to be broken? (if so, I'll try rolling back)

Comment: If you experience random crashes which are not software dependent, I would recommend to check your memory (memtest etc.)

Comment: @Maze thanks for the suggestion. I just ran memtester twice and it didn't report any errors. The system seems perfectly stable in a console terminal, so I am suspecting an issue with X11

Comment: Can you add your X.org log (the file could be named `Xorg.0.log` and found in `/var/log/`)

Comment: I had this errors, when my ssd was written full by error msgs from gtk. It shouldnt have happened, but the ssd died because of that. After a reboot i got lots of errors. The next reboot wasnt even possible.

Comment: @Anonymous I have added the Xorg log file. Near the end, it is crying about segmentation faults.

Comment: @WGRM that's a good suggestion. However, I have checked the ssd usage and there are many GB free on the partition.

Comment: I am not familiar with glamoregl but it seems to do with hardware acceleration. It used to be a standalone module, now merged with Xorg. This could be fixed pretty soon in a future release of Arch but as a workaround I would try to disable the relevant options in Xorg. Maybe [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/408582/190343) can help.

Comment: @Anonymous yes, that does it! If I use `startx -- :1 tty6 -extension GLX`, it logs in to LXDE and I am not seeing the X server crashes. Although, I am still seeing an issue I was getting previously with the system crashing when I open certain applications (it seems I have several issues stacked on top of each other here ...). If you feel like posting an answer, I'll be happy to give you the bounty points.

Comment: So, as you suspected, it seems there is an instability with the hardware acceleration in this build of X for Arch ARM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As posted in comments above:

The Xorg log file indicates that `glamoregl` is crashing, pointing to an issue with hardware acceleration.

Temporary workaround: start X while disabling GLX based on [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/408582/190343) ie:

```
startx -- :2 vt2 -extension GLX
```

One thing I was wondering is whether you have a specific proprietary/open source driver for your GPU (I understand it should be Mali graphics T764 for your model). [This post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/271934/installing-mali-drivers-archlinuxarm) suggests `xf86-video-armsoc-rockchip` and `veyron-libgl`. Possibly, I would also have a look at [developer.arm.com](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/graphics-and-gaming/mali-drivers)

Comment: This does work, thanks for your answer. However, since I changed the Xorg conf to disable GLX, lightdm is now not starting properly on boot. I guess that is probably for another question though. The GPU driver I am using is `panfrost`, which seems to be an open-source driver for the Mali GPUs. I think it is fairly new though and may not be entirely stable. It might be worth disabling the module to see if that improves stability.

Comment: It says [here](https://linux-sunxi.org/Mali#Panfrost_driver_.28Open_Source.29) that panfrost 'is a work in progress and not yet ready for general use'. Nice of them to bundle it as standard with the ARM linux kernel then (lol).

Comment: I blacklisted panfrost and the system seems a lot more stable. I'm not seeing the same Xorg crashes that I was before. Thanks so much for your help! :-)