# LibreOffice systematically crashes my Linux system

Tags: crash, libreoffice, openrc, artix-linux

When I launch LibreOffice, I get the widget with the LibreOffice logo (the one displayed while the application loads), then my screen blinks three/four times, then it turns black. All I can do at that point is a hard reset and reboot.

This is not a random event, it happens systematically, and only with LibreOffice.

No error is displayed.

The crash occurs with:

- The default LibreOffice included in my distro.
- With the LibreOffice binary downloaded from its website.
- With the AppImage version downloaded from its website.

These are my system details:

- Laptop: Lenovo Thinkpad E585 (AMD Ryzen 2700).
- Artix Linux - current version (= Arch without Systemd).
- KDE
- LibreOffice fresh (as of Nov 2022).
- Init system: OpenRC.

These are the files generated by LibreOffice in my home directory (~/.config/libreoffice/):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TrNJe9L9V9PeqEgexFqXYRA_hUjf2rVe/view?usp=share_link

Comment: Anything in logs/dmesg?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov - Where can I find these log files? They should be in my home directory, I suppose. But, even looking at the hidden files, I cannot see anything that resembles LibreOffice generated files.

Comment: `journalctl -b`

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov - I do not have the `journalctl` command, since I am using the OpenRC init system.

Comment: @Pietro Does your system have `/var/log/messages` or `/var/log/syslog`?  Also look for the X server log - see https://askubuntu.com/questions/26525/where-is-xserver-log-file-located for possible locations

Comment: @AndrewHenle - I have no `messages` nor `syslog` directories. This is the contents on my system: `ls /var/log/` -->
`audit  cron  cups  dmesg  everything  gssproxy  kernel  old  pacman.log  pwdfail  rc.log  samba  sddm.log  wtmp  Xorg.0.log`

Comment: @AndrewHenle - From `/var/log`, this is the output of `sudo grep -ir libre *`: everything/current:Jan 01 16:32:40 [sudo] pietrom : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/var/log ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/grep -i libre audit cron cups dmesg everything gssproxy kernel old pacman.log pwdfail rc.log samba sddm.log wtmp Xorg.0.log Xorg.0.log.old
everything/current:Jan 01 16:33:06 [sudo] pietrom : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/var/log ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/grep -ir libre audit cron cups dmesg everything gssproxy kernel old pacman.log pwdfail rc.log samba sddm.log wtmp Xorg.0.log Xorg.0.log.old

Comment: @Pietro `sudo grep -ir libre *` probably won't find the problem - `libre` (or whatever it's process name actually is) is likely just another process running as your UID, with normal permissions, which shouldn't  be enough to consistently lock up your system.  It's the X Windows display server process, which normally runs with `root` permissions, that has both the permissions and the ability to lock up your system.  I'm guessing that something Libre Office is doing, that no other program does, is making your X Windows server crash, hang, or otherwise cause problems and hanging the system.

Comment: This might help:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/573127/x11-crashing-on-login-arch-arm